# How can I force all IIS requests to go to one MVC controller & action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation that I figured would be quite easy to do in MVC. 
I want to have all request on a IIS site end up going to one specific action.

So I added the following to my route

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Everything",
            "{*foo}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

That works for most request going to the server, but there are some things the are ending being dealt with by other handlers:

- http://foo.com/ (works)
- http://foo.com/bar (works)
- http://foo.com/bar/baz (works)
- http://foo.com/bar/baz.txt (works - used to not work, but started working after adding runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" in web.config)
- http://foo.com/bar/baz. (does not work. stumped as to why)

This is in MVC 5, but I don't think that should really make a difference to the solution.

What trick am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the url rewrite module for this. Something like this should do it. (Obviously, change the url to whatever you want):

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Catch-All" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```